# CSS is not recognising checked attribute of checkbox when changing from jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, properties, checked

There is an issue with CSS and property :checked for checkbox when changing in jQuery.
When I use ('#checkbox').on('change') function, CSS is properly displaying element style

however when I use ('#checkbox').on('click') and then changing 'checked' in jQuery, CSS seems to ignore this setting.

It looks like CSS is applied to page after event is fired, and before jQuery is completed. I also tried to trigger "change" event manually, but without any success.

Is there any way to toggle checkbox 'on click' and make sure that correct CSS is applied?

**TO see this issue, visit jsfiddle and click first and then second checkbox**

https://jsfiddle.net/porzechowski/9yoqd736/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /**
     /* for first checkox we can see changed color, after checkox status is changed
     /* for second checkbox attribute checked and prop is changed, but CSS is not recognizing it
     **/

    // this is code for checkbox 1 - working

    $('body').on('change', '#checkbox1', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            console.log("checkbox1 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
            return;
        }
        console.log("checkbox1 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    // this is code for checkbox 2 - css not working
    $('body').on('click', '#checkbox2', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            console.log("checkbox2 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
            return;
        }
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).prop("checked", true)
        console.log("checkbox2 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.add-to-favorites-checkbox[type="checkbox"] + .add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon span {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background-color: red;
display: block;
}

.add-to-favorites-checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked + .add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon span {
background-color: green;
display: block;
}

input {
display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="add-to-bookmark add-btn">
<input class="add-to-favorites-checkbox js_bookmark-check" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" name="checkbox-favorites">
<label class="add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon" for="checkbox1"><span></span> Add to fav 1 </label>
</span>

<span class="add-to-bookmark add-btn">
<input class="add-to-favorites-checkbox js_bookmark-check" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="2" name="checkbox-favorites">
<label class="add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon" for="checkbox2"><span></span> Add to fav 2 </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `change` in `$('body').on('click','#checkbox2', function() {` and also

[check this post, prop vs attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        /**
         /* for first checkox we can see changed color, after checkox status is changed
         /* for second checkbox attribute checked and prop is changed, but CSS is not recognizing it
         **/

        // this is code for checkbox 1 - working

        $('body').on('change', '#checkbox1', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                console.log("checkbox1 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
                return;
            }
            console.log("checkbox1 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
        });

        // this is code for checkbox 2 - css not working
        $('body').on('change', '#checkbox2', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
                console.log("checkbox2 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
                return;
            }
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            $(this).prop("checked", true)
            console.log("checkbox2 status: " + $(this).attr('checked') + "=>" + $(this).prop('checked'));
        });

    });
```

```css
.add-to-favorites-checkbox[type="checkbox"] + .add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon span {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background-color: red;
        display: block;
    }

    .add-to-favorites-checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked + .add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon span {
        background-color: green;
        display: block;
    }

    input {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="add-to-bookmark add-btn">
<input class="add-to-favorites-checkbox js_bookmark-check" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1"
       name="checkbox-favorites">
<label class="add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon" for="checkbox1"><span></span> Add to fav 1 </label>
</span>

<span class="add-to-bookmark add-btn">
<input class="add-to-favorites-checkbox js_bookmark-check" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="2"
       name="checkbox-favorites">
<label class="add-to-favorites-checkbox-icon" for="checkbox2"><span></span> Add to fav 2 </label>
</span>
```